# ElementaryOS and Wireguard

Tags: vpn

Testing linux and started with Elementary OS. 
I am looking to finalize my install with wireguard. 
I am lost as far as how to install and the name of the package to install wireguard. 
I did run apt-get cache search/list but to no avail. 
Any light on this is much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Since Elementary uses the same package manager as Ubuntu, usually you can follow instructions written for that distribution.

NOTE: Elementary does not come with software-properties-common installed (which is required for `add-apt-repository`), so here's the steps I followed to install it.

1. `sudo apt install software-properties-common`
2. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wireguard/wireguard`
3. `sudo apt install wireguard`

[Source](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/vpn/set-up-wireguard-vpn-on-ubuntu/#install-wireguard)

Updated as per comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the (Source) it takes you to the page that go though the steps in setting up wireguard.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to install WireGuard via Snaps.

You can use [Snaptastic](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.bartzaalberg.snaptastic) from the AppCenter, or install via the command line like so:

```
snap install wireguard-ammp
```